# The memory with PHP FCGI continues to grow until the server does not respond

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-fcgid

I need advice to configure my server.

With these parameters, the memory keeps growing until the server dies without error (Apache or PHP).

Can someone help us improve performance?

Server

```
  Windows Server
  Apache 2.4.12
  8 GB RAM
```

Config

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt.c>
  ThreadsPerChild       125
  MaxRequestsPerChild     5000
  ThreadStackSize   8388608
</IfModule>

<IfModule fcgid_module> 
  FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
  FcgidIOTimeout 300
  FcgidBusyTimeout 300
  FcgidIdleTimeout 300
  FcgidIdleScanInterval 60

  FcgidOutputBufferSize 1073741824
  FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
  FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 0
  FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 0
  FcgidMaxProcesses 45
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 50
  FcgidProcessLifeTime 300
 FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

We realized that the antivirus (McAfee) was the main problem for not freeing process memory.

After that, we tweaked my config.

```
<IfModule fcgid_module> 
  FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
  FcgidIOTimeout 300
  FcgidBusyTimeout 300
  FcgidIdleTimeout 30
  FcgidIdleScanInterval 6
  FcgidOutputBufferSize 1073741824
  FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
  FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 0
  FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 0
  FcgidMaxProcesses 45
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 50
  FcgidProcessLifeTime 30
  FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 1
</IfModule>
```